# Are game-related mathematics welcome here?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, se-sites

We have a problem over at Gamedev.StackExchange where we have some excellent questions that are heavy on mathematics but a lot of us can't provide a good answer. A good example of [this is the following question.](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/70978/how-can-i-compute-a-jacobian-matrix-with-dual-quaternions) Are these questions suitable for migration to your cross answers?

These are very much game related but we lack qualifications to answer all of these evidently.

Comment: Games can produce exceedingly well-motivated math questions.  If that question is representative of the type of thing you'd like to post here, then by all means, go for it!

Comment: Curiously enough, the linked question looks more suitable for MSE than it does (from an outsider's POV) for GDSE!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22342854/what-is-the-optimal-algorithm-for-the-game-2048 (Kind of)

Comment: I would say that the linked question is by far the exception more than the rule; it's far more mathematical than virtually any other question I've seen on Gamedev.SE.  While I definitely agree that the deeply 'pure mathematics' questions can be asked over here (if anyone starts talking about 'double covers of SO(3)', run), I feel like the Gamedev site needs good mathematical game dev content _much_ more than math.SE needs the gamedev 'applied math' questions, and for the most part I'd love to see all but the most mathematical questions kept there.

Answer (score 28):

This looks perfectly suitable to me. A good rule of thumb is that if the underlying question is fundamentally mathematical, and answering would not require any specific non-mathematical knowledge, then the question is suitable here.

Comment: To further extend non-mathematical knowledge: Although *some* questions related to programming a mathematical concept (e.g. 3d rotation for computer graphics) have been answered here, if someone expects the average Math.SE user to be able to read (and willing to respond) to a block of code, they will most likely be disappointed.